# Invoice generation in Springboot in PDF and XLS format

Tags: spring-boot, pdf, xls, invoice

I am having requirement to generate invoices from data available in Database.
Which tool would be good in spring boot.
OpenPDF/Thymeleaf /Apache Poi?
Which tool would be ideal to use and where?
Any tutorial link would be appreciated
(1) Generate Invoice in PDF format
(2) Generate Invoice in XLS format.